# Why are (uninstalled) packages listed in the "Local" repository (in Synaptic) after an upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, synaptic

I just upgraded a computer from 10.10 to 11.04 using the `do-release-upgrade` command. (This was the first time I've actually done an upgrade.) I had a few PPA's in my setup, which got removed from my configuration during the upgrade. I've gone back and re-added those PPA's (like Thunderbird stable and Flash 11), and updated and upgraded. Now when I look in Synaptic, I see a lot of "orphaned" (?) packages in the "Local" origin. I can "Mark for Complete Removal" on those packages, but then I can't "Apply" those changes. What's going on here? Is it possible to clean these out to make the system "clean?"

[image: Local Origin in Synaptic]

Comment: `apt-get --purge autoremove simple-ccsm` -> `dpkg-query -l simple-ccsm` -> "rc  simple-ccsm"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this seems to be the answer:

http://johnlewis.ie/remove-residual-config-files-in-ubuntu-a-one-liner/

`aptitude -F %p search '~c' | xargs dpkg -P`

I tried putting something together just like this, but based on `deborphan`, and I might have left my system in a partially borked state. I'll start another question on that.

Comment: shorten this to `sudo aptitude purge ~c`