# How do I install missing dependencies on my system?

Tags: apt, synaptic, aptitude

I was fooling around trying to fix [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54701/why-are-uninstalled-packages-listed-in-the-local-repository-in-synaptic-aft), and I removed some important packages. When I realized that it was cleaning out more things that I had intended, I just rebooted, rather than try to find the forked process and stop it. Now I can see in `aptitude` that I have several broken packages, which do NOT show up in `synaptic`. Rather than try to install the missing packages (e.g., Python, YIKES!), the "resolution" is to remove 354 packages that are still installed which depend on what's missing. Is there a command to go through all the installed packages, and make sure that all of their dependencies are also installed? If I could just get a list, that would be useful, but, clearly, a command to just "do it" and install them would be better.

Comment: I would try to install `ubuntu-desktop` that should bring with it almost all you need. Also `apt-get install -f` should try to resolve dependencies problems.

Comment: ubuntu-desktop is already installed, so that doesn't do anything. I've seen `apt-get install -f` in several other places, but that doesn't do anything for me either. I actually DID GET IT FIXED (apparently) by just reinstalling python-doc. That made `aptitude` stop reporting any broken packages. However, I want to leave the question open for the general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the installation and/or `apt-get -f install` suggestions mentioned in comments, you can tell `aptitude` to find a different resolution by using the `,` and `.` keys to navigate through the list of available resolutions in the examine view (entered with `e`). Sometimes the first suggested resolution involves uninstalling packages, whereas the next few will involve upgrade/downgrade/re-install operations.

In addition, you can "accept" or "reject" proposals regarding individual packages by selecting them in the list at the top and using `a` or `r` keys respectively. This will force aptitude to find solutions that respect your requirements (although if you specify too many it may fail to find a resolution altogether).